# Bash sourcing of functions in other languages

Tags: bash

This is, perhaps, a silly question, but it's something that I've wondered about: is it possible to, say, define a Ruby/Python/Perl/etc. function in some file and then source it in Bash (to make it available anywhere in the current shell)?

At the moment, I "source" scripts/functions in other languages by creating a bash alias that executes that script... But I wonder if it's possible for Bash to interpret those other functions directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *that* hard. You have to take advantage of the language's features for specifying what code to run. Figuring out how to escape the code and the input is tricky. But its doable:

```
# source-lang.sh: define some bash functions that call other languages
perl_sqrt()
{
    export operand=$1
    perl <<'EOF'
        print sqrt($ENV{operand}),"\n"
EOF
}

python_log()
{
    a=$1
    b=$2
    if [ "$b" = "" ]; then
        b=$a
        a=10
    fi
    python <<EOF
import math
c = math.log($b) / math.log($a)
print c
EOF
}
```

---

```
$ source source-lang.sh
$ perl_sqrt 289
17
$ python_log 2 128
7.0
$ f=`perl_sqrt 1024`
$ echo $f
32
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's not that easy to do that!

You could write something that knows how to execute a given function in a given file (using the language's interpreter), but that goes beyond bash :)

Comment: Hey, you could see this as an opportunity to improve in your weakest language by implementing all those functions in that one :)

Comment: That's a good point - it's just hard to "reduce" myself to Bash when something like Perl is so tantalizing.  But that's a bit pompous, so I'd better get over it!